# Adding multiple users to actorId field in jbpm6

Tags: jbpm

I modified the Evaluation business process so that PMEvaluation task is assigned to two actors  john and inga. Both users are defined in UserGroupCallback. 
However , when PMEvaluation activity starts,a task creates only for user 'john'.
A task has not been created for user 'inga'.

The following is my UserGroupCallBack. 
If I set the actorId to 'inga' , a task creates for user inga. Therefore, this is nothing to do with UserGroupCallback.

@Alternative

```
public class CustomUserGroupCallback implements UserGroupCallback {

public boolean existsUser(String userId) {      
    return userId.equals("krisv") ||userId.equals("john") || userId.equals("inga") || userId.equals("mary") || userId.equals("Administrator");
}

public boolean existsGroup(String groupId) {        
    return groupId.equals("PM") || groupId.equals("HR") || groupId.equals("admin") ;
}

public List<String> getGroupsForUser(String userId,
        List<String> groupIds, List<String> allExistingGroupIds) {      
    List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (userId.equals("john") || userId.equals("inga")){            
        groups.add("PM");}
    else if (userId.equals("mary"))
        groups.add("HR");
    else if (userId.equals("krisv"))
        groups.add("admin");
    return groups;
  }
}
```

Please help me to set more users to actorId field.

Comment: What do you mean by "create tasks for the user?" If the task has multiple actors the task will need to be claimed. Can you share the code that you use to check that the task has being created?

Comment: Thanks. I checked the db again. I have made a mistake. The actual owner is null and the status is in Ready state. When an activity starts, i want to assign the same task to several users. For example, in the above scenario, one task needs to be created for john and another task needs to be created for inga. Is it possible to do something like that in jbpm 6.1? In the practical scenario, if we take an activity like 'Daily Standup Meeting', each member has their own task, until all of them finish , the main Daily Standup Meeting activity is not completed.